# How to "Launch" Android Gradle App using command line on emulator and physical device. Not just build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, command-line

How to use the command line to launch Android Gradle apps on emulator and physical device via command line.

Emulator is of Android Studio.

I tried `gradlew.bat assembleDebug` but it does not 'launch', it simply builds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Build Using Command-Line** ->

For building our app using the command line you can use -

```
gradlew assembleDebug (For debug app)
```

For install apk on the connected device -

```
gradlew installDebug
```

For more info, you can check -

> https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline

Comment: I noticed using `gradlew installDebug` it although installs apk on emulator or connected device. But compared to Android Studio `Run` button, it does not automatically like "opens" the app after installing.

If you have any idea how to make it "open" as well, please add to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I do it, on Windows, in PowerShell:

```
$Env:JAVA_HOME = 'C:\Android Studio\jre'
.\gradlew.bat assembleDebug
.\gradlew.bat installDebug
adb -d shell am start -n your.app.package.name/.MainActivity
```

Where `C:\Android Studio\jre` is the path to Android Studio's Java, instead of the system one. Might skip if you have JDK etc.

Then assembleDebug, installDebug like in other answers.

Finally! The actual answer: using adb to connect to current USB device `-d` and execute android manager `am` in the shell, using it to start app by `-n` package name, targeting `MainActivity`.

I check the current directory name to automatically determine the app name, but you might just as well provide it as an argument, or even regex the manifest.